# Marshling structure with a pointer to another structure

Tags: c#, c++, .net-core, marshalling

I'm writing DLL in C++ for JSON parsing to use it in .NET app.

So there are several structures in C++ part:

```
struct Person
{
  Person(uint32_t id = 0, wchar_t* name = nullptr, wchar_t* phone = nullptr,
         wchar_t* email = nullptr, wchar_t* postal = nullptr);

  uint32_t id;
  wchar_t* name;
  wchar_t* phone;
  wchar_t* email;
  wchar_t* postal;
};

struct Locale {
  Locale(uint32_t id = 0, wchar_t* iso = nullptr, wchar_t* description = nullptr);

  uint32_t id;
  wchar_t* iso;
  wchar_t* description;
};

struct Organization
{
  Organization(uint32_t id = 0, wchar_t* inn = nullptr, wchar_t* officialName = nullptr,
               wchar_t* shortName = nullptr, wchar_t* kpp = nullptr,
               wchar_t* ogrn = nullptr, wchar_t* address = nullptr,
               Person* contact = nullptr, Locale* locale = nullptr);

  uint32_t id;           
  wchar_t* inn;          
  wchar_t* officialName; 
  wchar_t* shortName;    
  wchar_t* kpp;          
  wchar_t* ogrn;         
  wchar_t* address;      
  Person* contact;       
  Locale* locale;        
};

struct Domain
{
  Domain(uint32_t id = 0, wchar_t* name = nullptr, Organization* organization = nullptr,
         Locale* locale = nullptr);

  uint32_t id;                
  wchar_t* name;              
  Organization* organization; 
  Locale* locale;             
};
```

And corresponding structures in C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public struct PersonStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public uint id;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string name;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string phone;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string email;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string postal;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public struct LocaleStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] 
    public uint id;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string iso;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string description;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public struct OrganizationStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public uint id;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string inn;          

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string officialName;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string shortName;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string kpp;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string ogrn;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string address;  

    public IntPtr contactPtr;

    public IntPtr localePtr;    
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public struct DomainStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public uint id;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string name;

    public IntPtr organizationPtr;

    public IntPtr localePtr;            
}
```

DLL interface functions in C look like this

```
CACHELIB_API Result getDomain(Domain** domain, uint32_t domainId);
```

And a method to import it to .NET app

```
[DllImport(LIB_PATH, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "getDomain")]
internal static extern Result DoGetDomain(out IntPtr domain, uint domainId);
```

All unmanaged memory is allocated by DLL with `CoTaskMemAlloc`.

To get value of `organizationPtr` in `DomainStruct` I used

```
var organization = Marshal.PtrToStructure<Structures.OrganizationStruct>(domain.organizationPtr);
```

So my question is, do I have to use `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(organization.contactPtr)` to free unmanaged memory?

Do I need to use `Marshal.DestroyStructure<PersonStruct>(organization.contactPtr)` before it?

How to do all this marshaling in a proper way?

Comment: You need `DestroyStructure` if the struct contains other structs by reference, eg `Person*`. Marshalling the *proper way* would be to preallocate buffers on the C# side for writing on the C++ side (and use classes instead of ref structs, getting free marshalling). But I'd venture to suggest you are reinventing the wheel, badly. There are many good JSON parsers for C#, which you should use, and all of them are written in C#, not C++

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Parsing in not the only point of this library. Yes, I know C# got fine JSON parsers, but this is our management's decision.

Comment: So as I said, if you make them classes instead of structs, you can do away with manual pointer fiddling and `IntPtr`. Just preallocate it on the C# side and pass it in for the C++ code to overwrite.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @Charlieface, much appreciated.